# building a json from jq

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, json, jq

I want to generate a json file in jq like this below :

```
{
  "cpe": "dabb8fbd-d7be-4175-abb4-c628bb8cf1b5",
  "ps": [ "Obev" ],
  "ets": 5,
  "pMap": {
      "aik": ["1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-1", "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-2", "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-3", "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-4", "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-5"]
    }
```

Here is what I am trying in jq -

```
inner2=$(jq -n --arg aik "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-1", "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-2", "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-3", "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-4", "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-5" \
              '$ARGS.named')

res=$(jq -n   --arg cpe "App" \
              --arg ps "["Obev"]" \
              --arg ets 5 \
              --argjson pMap "$inner2" \
              '$ARGS.named')
```

but it doesn't returns the JSON format as expected.
`ets` value if `5` which is int hence no quotes expected but it generates one
`pMap` value generates like this `"aik": {"1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-1, 1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-2, 1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-3, 1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-4, 1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-5"}`

here as per desired op the format is not getting generated

`ps` value is also not getting generated as per desired op

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jo` (see [here](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/)), which makes it easier to create JSON on the command line than what `jq` does.  It allows for creating arrays with `jo -a`.

```bsh
jo -p \
        cpe='dabb8fbd-d7be-4175-abb4-c628bb8cf1b5' \
        ps="$( jo -a Obev )" \
        ets=5 \
        pmap="$( jo aik="$( jo -a \
                "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-1" \
                "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-2" \
                "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-3" \
                "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-4" \
                "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-5" )" )"
```

Assuming that you are using a shell that has arrays, and that `ets` is the length of the `aik` array:

```bsh
data=(
        "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-1"
        "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-2"
        "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-3"
        "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-4"
        "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-5"
)

jo -p \
        cpe='dabb8fbd-d7be-4175-abb4-c628bb8cf1b5' \
        ps="$( jo -a Obev )" \
        ets="${#data[@]}" \
        pmap="$( jo aik="$( jo -a "${data[@]}" )" )"
```

The `-p` option for `jo` make sit pretty-print the output, so remove that when you are happy with that the document's structure is correct.

---

The corresponding `jq` command, assuming the array `data` exists, is

```bsh
jq -n \
        --arg cpe 'dabb8fbd-d7be-4175-abb4-c628bb8cf1b5' \
        --argjson ps "$( jq -n '$ARGS.positional' --args Obev )" \
        --arg ets "${#data[@]}" \
        --argjson pmap "$(
                jq -n --argjson aik "$( jq -n '$ARGS.positional' --args "${data[@]}" )" \
                        '$ARGS.named'
        )" \
        '$ARGS.named'
```

That is, use

```bsh
jq -n '$ARGS.positional' --args some arguments here
```

to create an anonymous array.

Comment: `jo` is https://github.com/jpmens/jo, yes?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, I usually link to https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/  I should do that in this answer too. Thanks.

Comment: @they unfortunately `command not found: jo` is not available as a standard package in the systems and cannot be installed externally due to security concerns

Comment: @Alex I added a `jq` bit at the end. Note that `jq` is also not a standard Unix command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to spend more time reading the jq manual: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

```bsh
values=(
    "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-1"
    "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-2"
    "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-3"
    "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-4"
    "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-5"
)

inner=$(jq -n --args '{aik: $ARGS.positional}' "${values[@]}")
echo "$inner"
```

```json
{
  "aik": [
    "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-1",
    "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-2",
    "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-3",
    "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-4",
    "1~4-b7-4c-bb-b~od1.y.1..aiq~s-an-6~-a-5"
  ]
}
```

Comment: jackman Thanks a lot, I went through the docs but could not find any reasons why this is not supported `"ps": [ "Obev" ]` when I do this `--arg ps "["Obev"]"`

Comment: because the inner quotes are not escaped, they will be removed by the shell.  Use `--argjson ps '["Obev"]'` Admittedly, jq is awkward to work with for building arbitrary json.